# Read browser URL from Xamarin form android for custom OAuth code sent from the IDP in redirect URL

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, oauth-2.0, xamarin.android, mobile-browser

I am trying to implement custom OAuth login into my Xamarin application.

I am hitting the OAuth API from browser when a Login button is clicked.

It is redirecting to my custom OAuth authentication page and after initial authentication it sends an auth code in the URL of the auth.html from my domain page. I need to read that URL and process further.

My code in the button click :

```
var apiEndpoint = "https://auth.example.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=myclientid&redirect_uri=https://example.com/apps/auth.html&state=STATE";
await Browser.OpenAsync("apiEndpoint", BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
```

I need to read the code from the URL when is is returned from my domain redirect uri as below:

```
https://orion.lexmark.com/winapps/auth.html?code=12358123-2200-4ga6-a806-8f60f5636ac8&state=STATE
```

I am very new to the xamarin world, any help on this will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to do mobile OAuth is to use a Private URI Schene URL such as this, which will then invoke the app with the login response when it is returned to the browser:

- com.mycompany. myapp:/callback

It is standard to also open the URL via an integrated form of the system browser - a Chrome Custom Tab on Android.

Developers usually also plug in the open source [AppAuth libraries](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android) to do the tricky work of using OAuth messages correctly. This will be harder in Xamarin though, due to the extra layers.

I would recommend having a look at AppAuth and at least borrowing some ideas from it. My [Android AppAuth Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2018/02/20/android-setup) explaims a fast working setup.

Comment: Gary, thanks for your reply, I was going through your blog. For our case we have two step OAuth flow. We authenticate via custom SAML provider in AWS cognito. 1st to get the auth code and then taking the code again call an API endpoint to get the tokens. So on the 1st flow I need to get the code from the url. and then call another api to get tokens, I am stuck on 1st flow.

Comment: The 2 step process is fine - your app only needs to talk to Cognito via OpenID Connect - if you use a Private URI Scheme you will be able to register it in the app, then receive the login response with the authorization code.

Comment: You should be able to re-point the small AppAuth sample to your own environment and prove that it works the way you want before updating your Xamarin app.

Comment: It is finally working as expected. There were two changes made. 1. the case sensitive cognito redirect url and the datascheme in the xamarin app.
Thanks for your help.